# win32api best way to create multiple controls

Tags: c++, winapi

Im just learing to code for the win32 api.. And one thing that i cannot seem to find some ideas for is were to put the code when creating multiple controls..

For example:

Im writing a program that have 8 separete edit boxes + 8 statics.. Should i just dump everyone inside of WM_CREATE? Or should i create a separate function and call that from WM_CREATE?
Ive also tried to think of somekind of loop, but the placements for the different controls is a problem there..

How are you professionals doing it? :)

Comment: We don't create GUIs in code, we use visual UI designers, dialog resources, etc and let the framework/OS do all the hard work of setting up the UI at runtime for us.

Comment: I create GUIs in code (WinAPI & X11). :S Depending on external & 3rd party frameworks is not something I often do and I hate having to do that to get something done.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question differs from a [general opinions question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), especially since you're asking whether or not to split out some code into a function (that may very well be in another function or not). Ultimately it's up to you, and your needs. Windows does provide the dialog system, which allows you to store a list of controls and positions in a resource and have the system load your GUI from that instead, but again, up to you :/

Comment: @Brandon hope I'm not sounding rude here, but what do you use alongside X11 then? GTK+? Xaw? Or have you built your own widget toolkit (or forego even that)?

Comment: @andlabs I use raw `X11` and `WinAPI`. I wrote my own wrappers around it. So I do something like: `Button* b = new Button(...);` where `Button` and all other "controls" inherit from a base class `Control`. For GUI Windows, I made a wrapper so it does: `GLWindow* w = new GLWindow(....);` where `GLWindow` and `BasicWindow` inherits from an abstract class `Window`. It's just easier for me. Rarely I use kits and when I do, the choice is usually `GTK`. It's a huge turn off that the C++ standard doesn't have stuff like this and everything is a 3rd party library -_-

Comment: Ah, I see. Whatever works, I guess =P Should the C++ standards have this? It would monopolize UI library choices and designs across devices... (probably not a discussion for here though)